# Is a finite regular, bipartite graph (with equal partite sets) always vertex transitive?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I came across a particular type of graph which is finite, regular and bipartite. I suspect that it is also vertex transitive. Is it true in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. For instance, let $G$ be the disjoint union of even cycles $C_1$ and $C_2$. So we have that $G$ is 2-regular, finite, and bipartite with equal partite sets. However, if $u \in V(C_1)$ and $v \in V(C_2)$ and $|V(C_1)| \neq |V(C_2)|$ then there is no automorphism that takes $u$ to $v$. Perhaps if we require that $G$ be connected then the statement is true.

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, even connectedness is not enough for it. Just now, I came across Folkmann graphs.

Comment: Great example, thanks for sharing. Yeah, if you're interested in constructing a large class of vertex transitive graphs, you might be interested in looking at Cayley graphs, which are constructed from a group and a symmetric generating set. Not every vertex transitive graph is a Cayley graph (for instance, the Petersen graph is the smallest vertex-transitive graph that is not a Cayley graph), but Cayley graphs have neat properties.